# JSON structure to insert multiple Account records in one REST API call

Tags: rest-api, json

As per the documentation i understood that we can create account in the following way.

Example for creating a new Account

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@newaccount.json"
```

Example request body newaccount.json file for creating a new Account

```
{
    "Name" : "Express Logistics and Transport"
}
```

Example response body after successfully creating a new Account

```
{
    "id" : "001D000000IqhSLIAZ",
    "errors" : [ ],
    "success" : true
}
```

Is there a way to create multiple accounts in one shot and if it is possible what could be the JSON structure? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Right now SFDC standards REST API does not support bulk insert.  So you have two options.

1) Use BULK API ( https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/)

2) Create your custom API that accept list of accounts. Here is example of how to do it. Check Mohits's answer. [Is it possible to pass sObjects to the REST api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10853/is-it-possible-to-pass-sobjects-to-the-rest-api)

Comment: or, if willing to abandon REST, use SOAP API

Comment: Yes, SOAP makes more sense for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Composite API
2. POST Composite SObject Tree
3. Endpoint:

> /services/data/v54.0/composite/tree/Account/

4. Body Structure:

{
"records" :[{
"attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},
"name" : "SampleAccount",
"phone" : "1234567890",
"website" : "www.salesforce.com",
"numberOfEmployees" : "100",
"industry" : "Banking",
"Contacts" : {
"records" : [{
"attributes" : {"type" : "Contact", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
"lastname" : "Smith",
"title" : "President",
"email" : "sample@salesforce.com"
},{
"attributes" : {"type" : "Contact", "referenceId" : "ref3"},
"lastname" : "Evans",
"title" : "Vice President",
"email" : "sample@salesforce.com"
}]
}
},{
"attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref4"},
"name" : "SampleAccount2",
"phone" : "1234567890",
"website" : "www.salesforce2.com",
"numberOfEmployees" : "100",
"industry" : "Banking"
}]
}

5. Source:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/requests_composite_sobject_tree.htm