# Regarding Rest Services using Rest Api

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest, rest-service

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account13/*')

global with sharing class  MyRestResource13 {
@HttpPost
 global static string sendAccount(){

        RestRequest req  = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        system.debug(req);
        system.debug(res);
       // map<account,object> account1  = new map<account,object>();

        Blob body = req.requestBody;
        system.debug(body);
        string body1 =body.toString();
        system.debug(body1);


        dto df = (dto)json.deserialize(body1 ,dto.class);
        dto dl = new dto(df.name,df.phone,df.website);

        system.debug(df);

        Account a = new account();
        //a.name=df.name;
        insert a;
        system.debug(dl);
        return json.serialize(dl);

        }



public class dto
{
public string Name{get;set;}
public string phone{get;set;}
public string website{get;set;}
  public dto(String Name,String phone,String Website)
  {
    this.Name=Name;
    system.debug(Name);
    this.phone=phone;
    system.debug(phone);
    this.website=website;
    system.debug(website);
   }
}
}
```

**If we Change the Annotations @Httpput and @Httpget also it is Working,then what is the difference between put,get and post,Please anyone Explain with above Code**

Comment: check this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation.htm Apex REST annotations section

Comment: @sdfcweb the Document specify put method is used for creates and updates the resource,post method is used for creates a new resource,get method is used for request sent and retrieve from Server,Eventhough if you use put annotation instead of post Annotation ,post also updating the resource how and then how it is working Please Explain with Example

Comment: Please anyone Guide Me to Show the Difference

Comment: @itzmukeshy 7,@Olekisy,@Martin,@jenny anyone Guide Me to show the Difference

Comment: It won't make any difference to you, as you are service provider. But it will affect those who use our service. Based on the HTTP method they chose, they will do different operation.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy then how?

Comment: create two salesforce orgs and then refer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/117246/22234 and create classes accordingly. After that try changing @-HttpPost to @-HttpGet in source org. You will see the impact.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy actually i Have tried with the PostMan,In Post Man whatever the Http Method is Given,Same Method should be Given in Apex class

Comment: yes that is what is the use. So you write logic like, creating new account when service is called using 'PUT'/ updating an account when using 'POST'/ getting all account details when using 'GET'/ deleting an account when accessed using 'DELETE' and so on. But here all the calls are to the same url.

Comment: If you see salesforce given default REST documentation you will get more clear idea.

Comment: Are you asking about diff between POST and GET method in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between PUT, GET, and POST is almost just convention. If you're writing a service which is querying a database and returning result(s), you'd tend to make it GET. If you're creating an object, you'd tend to use PUT. Since you're writing the service, you can choose the method that makes most sense. For your sendAccount() method, I'd use PUT. That said, I've used REST services which use GET for everything (that has the slight advantage of being what web browsers use, so you can test your service with just a browser).

Technically, there are differences in how the different verbs should behave and the gory details available in these two links:

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Please make sure with Example,I am not able to get it,how if i use put annotation for creating object

Comment: how we can check with rest services using Web Browser Please Guide Me

Comment: As someone said above, you're writing the service, so you can choose which annotation you think is most appropriate. I'm not sure what else there is to say on that.

Comment: Then I want to Learn Difference Give some Practical Learning