# Passing Sobject to apex rest method using JSON

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, sobject, apexrest

I am exploring a way to pass a sobject to an apex class. Below is my apex class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/resturl/*')
global with sharing class check {
    public boolean Hide {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public check(sobject__c customobject) {
        Hide = false;
        customobject.field1__c = false;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static Boolean save(sobject__c customobject) {
        check objectcheck = new check(customobject);
        return objectcheck.saves();
    }

    private saves() {

        try {
            // do some stuff
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

I am calling this rest method save() using a JSON request formed in workbench, which looks like this:

```
{
  "customobject" : {
  "field1__c" : "true"
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to pass a custom Sobject in JSON with a custom field named field1__c?

In response of calling the method from workbench I do get a 200 HTTP response code, but I do get a false returned instead of true. So before I go into debugging I just want to make sure if I am passing the Sobject correctly in JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this format:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "customobject__c"
    },
    "field1__c": true
}
```

This is assuming that you are writing to a proper boolean object. This should work because it's a serialized output from one of my own custom objects.

To get the JSON data, you should get it from the rest body, ie:

```
@HttpPost
global static String save(){
    String body = System.RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
    customobject__c obj = (customobject__c)JSON.deserialize(body,customobject__c.class); 
}
```

For more info, go [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm)
Also thanks to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10853/is-it-possible-to-pass-sobjects-to-the-rest-api?rq=1) post for helping me correct a problem with my original answer.

Comment: I believe I am passing the JSON correctly. In my try block where I have //do stuff I was using an object which I get from a standard controller. Since there is not VF page in rest calls it was throwing an error. Now when I removed that object things worked. But thanks for your input this is a different way of passing a JSON from mine.